# Problem with react hooks, cant create a chatroom

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-query

I'm trying to create a chatroom using mutation and react hooks. I cant find the solution to the error i'm getting. The error is: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Beneath you see 2 code examples of the hook.ts file and my screen

```
import { getStateFromPath } from '@react-navigation/native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-query';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Chatroom } from '../entities/Chatroom';

function helper() {
    const token = useSelector((state: any) => state.user.idToken)
    
    return {token};
}

const baseURL = "";

export const useFetchChatrooms = () => {
    var { token } = helper()

    const fetchChatrooms = async() => {
        return await axios.get(baseURL + token)
    }
    const {isLoading, isError, data, error} = useQuery('chatrooms', fetchChatrooms)

    let chatrooms: Chatroom[] = []
    for(const key in data?.data) {
        const chatroom = data?.data[key]
        chatrooms.push(new Chatroom(chatroom.title, chatroom.status.UNREAD, '', new Date()))
    }
    return{
        isLoading, isError, chatrooms, error
    }
}

export const usePostChatrooms = () => {
    return useMutation((newChatroom: Chatroom) => {
        var { token } = helper()
        return axios.post(baseURL + token, newChatroom)
    })
}
```

And the screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useFetchChatrooms, usePostChatrooms } from '../hooks/rqhooks';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { StackParamList } from "../typings/navigations";
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { Chatroom, Status } from '../entities/Chatroom';


type ScreenNavigationType = NativeStackNavigationProp<
    StackParamList,
    "ReactQueryScreen"
>


export default function ReactQueryScreen() {
    const [title, onChangeTitle] = React.useState('');

    const navigation = useNavigation<ScreenNavigationType>()

    const { isLoading, isError, chatrooms, error} = useFetchChatrooms();

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    // Mutations
   const {mutate: createChatroom} = usePostChatrooms()



    if(isLoading) {
        return <Text>Loading...</Text>
    }    

    if(isError) {
        return <Text>Error: {error}</Text>
    }

    const renderChatroom = ({ item }: { item: any }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    );

    const rqHandleAddChatroom = () => {
        const chatroom: Chatroom = new Chatroom(title, Status.UNREAD, '', new Date());
        createChatroom(chatroom, {onSuccess: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries('chatrooms')})
    } 
    

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
            data={chatrooms}
            renderItem={renderChatroom}
            keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
            />
            <Text>react query</Text>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={onChangeTitle}
                value={title}
                placeholder="Chatroom name"
            />
            <Button onPress={rqHandleAddChatroom} title="Create chatroom"/>

        </View>
        
    );
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
})
```

Comment: And I'm using firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function named `helper` calls `useSelector`. As per the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), Hooks can only be called:

- from functional components
- from custom hooks

A custom hook is a function that starts with the word `use`. So you'd just need to rename `helper` to `useHelper`

```
- function helper() {
+ function useHelper() {
    const token = useSelector((state: any) => state.user.idToken)
    
    return {token};
}
```

and then call it as:

```
var { token } = useHelper()
```

those calls are then again valid because they also are made in custom hooks (`usePostChatrooms`).

There is an [eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) from the react team that can help you spot such errors

---